# Taxes as "US employee" but working from home country

Tags: united-states, taxes, working-abroad

I'm being offered a remote position for an US company. The recruiter mentioned that I will have to pay taxes in the US and also they will process my visa, but I'll continue working from Costa Rica (never working from the US).

Just to be clear: I'm not trying to evade taxes. Just I don't want to sign for a overcomplex process that may be worse than my current total compensation.

Is right that I would have to pay US taxes without being an US citizen, without working there and maybe just a visa.

Given the previous situation, I could pay taxes there and ask for a tax return?

I would have to pay taxes in my home country? And being double taxed... (My country don't have any relief treatment for double taxing with US).

I would have to pay US taxes on other income that I generate in my home country?

Is that normal? Should I ask the recruiter for a more traditional/simpler payment arrangement.

If I have stocks: I wouldn't be able to say that I don't have economic activity in the US. So I would have to pay additional US taxes on my current stocks, right?

Comment: Scam alert: if you're working remotely from your home country then there's no sensible reason for needing a visa. If the next step of the "recruitment" process involves you paying some sort of deposit or processing fee or whatever, then it's 99.99999% certainly a scam.

Comment: You don’t pay US income tax, unless you are a US citizen or work in the USA. You are neither. Scammers often use red flags like this to filter out the less gullible. And as brhans says, if they ask you for money it’s most definitely a scam.

Comment: Thanks, but no, definitely is not a scam. Is a well know company and the recruiter and hiring manager is well known. Afaik they are new with the remote/abroad offers and may be just trying to extrapolate the remote/within USA process to other countries.

Comment: Be careful. Scammers have used the names of decent companies before. At least check on the company’s own website if they are hiring. And if they ask for money, it’s a scam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The recruiter mentioned that I will have to pay taxes in the US and also they will process my visa, but I'll continue working from Costa Rica (never working from the US).

If the recruiter is not a licensed CPA/Attorney/EA paid to provide tax advice then they shouldn't. And if they do - ignore them. That's nonsense. If you're not a US citizen/green card holder, and were not physically present in the US - the US tax laws do not apply to you.

> I would have to pay taxes in my home country? And being double taxed... (My country don't have any relief treatment for double taxing with US).

You would have to pay taxes in your home country. Don't know about how Costa Rica handles foreign taxation, but it does not in fact have a tax treaty with the US so double taxation is a possibility (but as I said -  not relevant to you).

> I would have to pay US taxes on other income that I generate in my home country?

Of course not.

> Is that normal? Should I ask the recruiter for a more traditional/simpler payment arrangement.

Traditional arrangement would be that they hire you through their local office. Alternatively you can work as an independent contractor and invoice them for pay. It just as well could be that the company has absolutely no knowledge on how to handle foreign employees so they're saying nonsense just so that you agree to make things "easy" for them and be treated as if you're local.

> Is right that I would have to pay US taxes without being an US citizen, without working there and maybe just a visa.

No. If your foot never steps in the US you don't even need a visa.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask them for the more traditional arrangement of independent contractor or a branch office. Because with what they proposed for me would be better to just relocate to the US.